# Unit method search list in the IDE is empty

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have been moving from a few days to the 10.4.2 version of Delphi. I immediately noticed a strange problem, the list of the IDE that is used to search for the methods related to the loaded unit in some cases remains empty, so it is not possible to use it to pass to a certain procedure.
After some tests I realized that the problem essentially depends on a procedure, which in my code is present in the definition of all the packages that are used as plugins by the main program, the responsible procedure is the following:

```
function Command (Id: integer; Params: ansistring; Proc: TProc <TObject> = nil): ansistring; override;
```

to give the problem is essentially "= nil", if I remove it, all the methods magically appear again in the list.
This did not happen on RIO (I haven't tried the previous versions of Sydney), does anyone have any idea how to fix it or will we have to wait for the new update?

Comment: If you have reproducible code that is not working well with LSP code insight, please file bug report on https://quality.embarcadero.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on *Classic Code Insight*.

Open Options -> User Interface -> Editor -> Language -> Code Insight tab

There you have combo box where you can choose Code insight manager. Instead of *Delphi (Language Server Protocol)* you can use *Delphi (Classic Code Insight)* that was used in previous Delphi versions.

[image]

Comment: Ok, it bothers me because the new code insight was one of the reasons why I had updated to 10.4.2, I'll see if I use the old mode.
In time I try to report the error.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunate. LSP still needs more work. On the bright side, some things that were not working in Classic Code Insight have been fixed in Sydney, so upgrade is still worthwhile.

Comment: Sorry I just tried your suggestion that seemed to me to work, but even setting the ide on the Delphi Classic version continues to give the same problem, is it necessary to change other settings as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Some code just breaks Code Completion. I suggest reporting the issue in Quality Portal https://quality.embarcadero.com/